# How to return value of menu navigation label

Tags: php, wordpress

When the user clicks a menu item, I need to return the navigation label of the corresponding item.

For e.g. my main menu is :

Home|About Us| Page1 | Page2

If the user clicks "Page1", I need to return value of Page1 i.e. "Page1".

I need to return this in a PHP variable.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Add it as a `$_GET` parameter `index.php?label=Home`

Option 2: include a file in the header that has an associative array where key is the page name (index,about etc.) and value is the label name (Home,About Us etc.) and get the current label with the name of the current page (`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`)

Example:

```
$labels['index'] = "Home";
$labels['about'] = "About Us";

$currentLabel = $labels[$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']];
```